# Return the last date from a range

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table that I need to get the last day of each month, for each year.  My table has the days and months from 2007 to 2015, and the months don't always have the same amount of days in them.

I'm looking for a formula that will look in my range, and return the last day for each month, depending on the year.  (My data doesn't have data each day, so the last day on a calendar may not necessarily be the last day in my data).

Here's a (very) short example of my dates info (cols A, B, and C):

```
12  2009    24
12  2009    28
12  2009    29
12  2009    30
12  2009    31
1   2010    4
1   2010    5
1   2010    6
1   2010    7
1   2010    8
1   2010    11
1   2010    12
1   2010    13
```

So it's Month, Year, Day, going from `1 2007 1` to `8 2015 31`.

What kind of formula can I use to return the last date, from each month, per year?

I've tried formulas with Max, but can't quite get it.  Unfortunately there's no `MaxIf()` function, which would theoretically work.  Here's something I've tinkered with,

`=INDEX(MAX(Day),MATCH(C22&MONTH(DATEVALUE($B23&" 1")),Year&Months,0))`
, where `c22` is "2007" and `B23` is "January"

Edit: [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpH47.jpg) if it's a little easier.  I'm trying to return the "crime" number for the last day in each month, each year.

Edit 2:  Sorry if I wasn't clear - the dates will ***not*** necessarily follow the calendar.  The data is coming from basically stock trading, which isn't open on the weekends and some random days.  Thus, I need to use the dates in the document to determine the last day, I can't rely on just using the true last day of each month (according to the calendar).

Therefore, I can't use just `date` or `EODate()` or `edate` alone.  I also am aware that there's a way to use `date` and set holidays, and only use weekdays.  That also won't likely work exactly, as I don't know what holidays to add in.

Edit 3:  Temporary Solution:
In the mean time, what I have done is gone down the list of months/year/days, and deleted all rows *except* the last date. So in my above table, I deleted the rows until `12 2009 31`, then deleted the next until `1 2010 31`, etc.  I then created a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIZrc.jpg) based off this, and used `Vlookup` to get the last day. ([Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj5WZ.jpg)).  It's kludgy, but worked.  I'm still super interested in a formula answer though, I can do it with VBA I just am surprised it's this complex :O

Comment: If you have Excel 2003 the **EOMONTH** formula will need the analysis toolpak adding, an alternative is `=DATE(B1,A1+1,0)` (day 0 of the following month).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [EOMONTH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628):

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1),0)
```

It finds the end of the month for any given date.

The '0' in the end means the current month of the date given, '1' would give the end of the next month. '-1' would give end of the prior month.

As was pointed out by Darren, this only works post 2003 excel.

Edit:

So this formula will get the friday before if the last day of month lands on weekend.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1),0))=1,EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1),0)-2,IF(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1),0))=7,EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1),0)-1,EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1),0)))
```

I am still thinking about holidays, Though there are only a few that do or could possibly land on the last day of the month.  I am just thinking outloud, but you could do a vlookup on those dates and manually put in a factor to subtract from the date.  Becuase the problem is when the holiday lands on a Monday or a sunday, then you would subtract 3, Saturday 2 and all other days 1.

Edit2:

I found an array formula that will work:

```
=MAX(IF($B$1:$B$13 & $A$1:$A$13 = B1 & A1,$C$1:$C$13))
```

I cringe to point this out:

1) Change the Ranges to match your data.
2) It is an array formula so ctrl-shift-enter to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  Is using a `date()` at all the way to go? I was thinking to pretend the dates are just numbers, and treat them as such - so I'm just looking for the largest number in a range, determined by the year and month.

Comment: @BruceWayne This would be a lot easier in vba.  But I see where you are going, you already have the last working day of the month in the list you just need to know how to mine it, Let me think on it.

Comment: I've found a temporary solution, and am slightly surprised that it'd need VBA.  I'll update my OP with my temporary solution.  Sorry for the confusion regarding the dates, I hope it's more clear now!

Comment: Bam! The Max/If worked! I don't know why I didn't think of that before. It was in my head that it is a simple "maxif" ...I'll chalk it up to being Friday.  Thanks a lot Scott!

Comment: @BruceWayne, "Maxif" was exactly what I googled and found something I could modify for your specific problem.

Comment: \*facepalm\* , I should've searched first. ...I'm glad it's Friday :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
=EDATE(DATE(B1,A1,C1),1)-DAY(EDATE(DATE(B1,A1,C1), 1))
```

Which basically converts it to a date, adds a month to it, and subtracts the days of the month so it's the end of the previous month.

Or as @Scott Craner points out, EOMONTH(DATE(B1,A1,C1), 0) does exactly the same thing.

If you're looking for the last weekday, you could try this:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(B14,A14+1,0))=1,DATE(B14,A14+1,0)-2,IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(B14,A14+1,0))=7,DATE(B14,A14+1,0)-1,DATE(B14,A14+1,0)))
```

which checks if it's a Sunday or Saturday, and moves back a day or two.

If you have a list of specific holidays, you would have to add something like the the countif(range, date)>1 and then backtrack to a weekday which is not a holiday itself (eg. backtracking Dec 25 on a Tuesday all the way back to Friday Dec 21).  If this is the case, you would be better of with a custom function instead of a crazy one-liner formula.

Comment: Hmm - that's interesting! I'll check that out, clever use of `e/Date()`.

Comment: Thanks again for this, @ScottCraner as well.  Sorry I wasn't clear - I edited the OP.  My sheet's last day is not necessarily the calendar's last day (I'm using trading days, which take off weekends and random holidays). Thus, a formula needs to be able to search what days I *do* have.  Does that make sense?  Is this harder to do than I thought?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the month in cell A1 and the year in cell B1, the date of the last day of its month is:

`=DATE(B1, A1 + 1, 0)`

Basically, Excel allows you to specify the "zero-th" day of the month to mean the day before the first day of the month

Comment: As per the OP, the months, years, days, are split into separate columns,  Your formula should resemble Darren's

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do it without a list of holidays but if you are able to create a list of holidays to exclude you can use:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(EOMONTH(date(B1,A1,C1),0),0,1,E1:E5)
```

where the E1:E5 are the holidays you are excluding.